# Calculate Histogram based on Hue & Saturation using OpenCV in Android

Tags: android, opencv

I'm developing an Android app. In which I'm trying to implement the `Imgproc.calcHist` function for calculating the histogram based on both hue & saturation of the image simultaneously. The syntax provided in android opencv i.e -

```
void org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.calcHist(List<Mat> images, MatOfInt channels, Mat mask, Mat hist, MatOfInt histSize, MatOfFloat ranges)
```

is not allowing me to pass 2 dimensional array for parameters- histSize & ranges. Whereas, in my Visual C++ program having the syntax as -

```
void calcHist(const Mat* images, int nimages, const int* channels, InputArray mask, OutputArray hist, int dims, const int* histSize, const float** ranges, bool uniform=true, bool accumulate=false )
```

allows me for passing 2 dimensional array of values for histSize & ranges. Therefore, my Visual C++ program is running absolutely well for my application.

I'm getting the runtime error at my Android App as follows -

> (-215)rsz==dims*2||(rsz==0 && images.depth(0)==CV_8U) in function void
>   cv::calcHist(cv::InputArray...........)

Kindly, provide me the solution to overcome this problem.

Comment: have a look the tutorial for histogram comparison, there they use 2D HS histograms afair. Hope you can adapt it to android opencv... http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html ah... ok... your c++ version works... but maybe there is some hint in the tutorial...

Comment: @Micka i have the same problem! 
Can you also see here ,please : http://answers.opencv.org/question/76345/calchist-always-fails-android-opencv/ thanks